# how to override the element.style using css

Tags: html, css

I have HTML Div tag as follows

```
<div class="dhx_view" view_id="calendar1" style="border-width: 0px 0px 1px; margin-top: 0px; width: 1562px; height: 342px;">
```

CSS as follows:

```
element.style {
  border-width: 0px 0px 1px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  width: 1562px;
  **height: 342px;**
}
```

Now I want to change the height: 342px to 372px using CSS

Comment: You must set `!important` after propery value e.g. `.dhx_view { margin-top: 0 !important; }`

Comment: .dhx_view i cant use it, can you give combination with view_id="calendar1"

Answer (score 7):

The only way to override an inline style in your stylesheet is by using the `!important` rule.

```
element.style {
  border-width: 0px 0px 1px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  width: 1562px;
  height: 342px !important;
}
```

Also check this [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/U9dR3/)

Answer (score 3):

## [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/cexil/1/edit?html,css,output)

use **!important** for height property to override inline style and make sure you use the right class name. element.style would work only in firebug or dev tools.

```
.dhx_view {
  background-color: #000;
  border-width: 0px 0px 1px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  width: 1562px;
  height: 372px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add another CSS definition.

```
.dhx_view{
  height:374px;
}
```

This will override the previous CSS definition as long as it is loaded after the first in the HTML page.  It will also keep the other rules in that style and just override the height.

Also, if you're going to assign a CSS class to an element, put all of the CSS in there.  I wouldn't mix inline styles with stylesheets.  It's just easier to maintain that way.

**Edit:**
I originally thought that the `element.style` was CSS that you had defined [which repeats the inline styles] but I think it may for reference and not code.  In that case, you can't just add another CSS class to override the original definition because - as a few people pointed out - the inline styles can't be overwritten by CSS, without using the `!important` declaration.

So your options are to use CSS without inline styles, or use inline styles with the `!important` flag.

Comment: .dhx_view i cant use it can you give combination with id

Comment: It won't work, because the other height is specified inline, which overrules all styles that are defined in a stylesheet.

Comment: Your code already uses it.  If you want to do it with ID, you'll need to first assign an ID to the element and then change the `.` to `#` in the code above.

Comment: @LinkinTED - That's why I recommended losing the inline styles.

Comment: Ahh... I thought that the `element.style` thing was CSS that he was also using in addition to inline styles.  Amending my response and upvoting yours.